# union of sigma algebra (power set)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I understand that union of sigma algebra is not a sigma algebra. But is union of power sets a sigma algebra?

Comment: Union of the power set with what exactly? i.e. Let $S$ be a set and let $2^S$ denote the power set of $S$. You are asking if $S \cup A$ is a $\Sigma$-algebra, but what is $A$?

Comment: I meant power sets. Sorry! A is also a power set

Answer (score 0):

A $\sigma$-algebra must be defined with respect to some underlying set. If $(\mathcal A_i)_{i\in I}$ are $\sigma$-algebras of subsets of the set $X$, then we know that it is not necessarily the case that $\mathcal A:=\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. If each $\mathcal A_i$ is a power set, then in fact $\mathcal A_i=2^X$ for each $i$, since a $\sigma$-algebra must contain the whole space $X$. In this case it is trivially true that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra since it is also equal to $2^X$.

If we do not require the $\sigma$-algebras to have the same underlying set then it doesn't really make sense to take their union.

Comment: Thank you Jason. This really helps in understanding $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about is this.  Let $\mathscr A = {\mathscr P}(X)$, $\mathscr B = {\mathscr P}(Y)$
be the power sets of distinct (but not necessarily disjoint) sets $X$ and $Y$, and 
consider $\mathscr A \cup \mathscr B \subseteq \mathscr P(X \cup Y)$.
This is not a $\sigma$-algebra because it does not contain the whole space $X \cup Y$.  In fact, in general it's not even a $\sigma$-ring, because
it won't contain $A \cup B$ for nonempty $A \in \mathscr A$ and $B \in \mathscr B$.